Vectorize a sampling of a dataframe based on filtered conditions?
I have two dataframes, one which has three variables (one discrete, two continuous) and the other which has the same, except with also an additional 4th variable. For the purposes of a minimum reproducible example, I use random data, but in reality these variables are related to each other.
Anyway, for the first dataframe, which is always of significant length (minimum 100k rows), I need to assign values for the "additional 4th variable". I do this by filtering the second dataframe to similar conditions, and then randomly sampling the fourth variable from this filtered dataframe. This works perfectly for my application. However, it's rather slow to iterate over a very long dataframe like this. I'm wondering if there is a more clever vectorized way of doing this operation. My thoughts are to maybe bin the three variables, then assemble filtered versions of the second dataframe for all bin combinations up-front, and then somehow to query these pre-filtered dataframes and sample. But I'm not sure if this is a sensible method. Any thoughts?
Here's an example of my current technique below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# df1
varA1 = [random.randint(1,3) for i in range(1000)]
varB1 = [random.uniform(0, 50) for i in range(1000)]
varC1 = [random.uniform(0, 100) for i in range(1000)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':varA1,'B':varB1,'C':varC1})

# df2 - reference, look-up.
varA2 = [random.randint(1,3) for i in range(1000)]
varB2 = [random.uniform(0, 50) for i in range(1000)]
varC2 = [random.uniform(0, 100) for i in range(1000)]
varD2 = [random.uniform(0, 1000) for i in range(1000)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':varA2,'B':varB2,'C':varC2,'D':varD2})

# Assign a value for "D" in Df1, based on values in Df2, considering similar values of other parameters.
df1['D'] = np.nan
for r in df1.iterrows():
    temp = df2.loc[(df2['A']==r[1]['A'])& \
               (df2['B']>=r[1]['B']-5)& \
               (df2['B']<=r[1]['B']+5)& \
               (df2['C'] >= r[1]['C']-10) & \
               (df2['C'] >= r[1]['C']+10),:]
    df1.loc[r[0],'D'] = temp['D'].sample().values


This procedure is called Imputation and is used in ML to replace Nulls. Please explain better what you are after - Getting D value from other rows which share ALL A-C values?

In Dataset 1 (without "D"), I need to assign each timestamp a D that is appropriate given the conditions a, b, c. Hence why I filter Dataset 2 to similar conditions of a, b, and c and then take a random sample from D.  They won't "share all A-C values" because B and C are continuous variables. Just "close enough" hence my filtering / binning.

I tried an approach with binning, and doing the filtering of df2 only one time for each possible bin combination. I then use a random selection from the already-filtered datasets.
Even though this implementation also still uses pandas .apply, the function is simpler (not requiring the dataframe filtering which seems to be slow over lots of values).
On my machine, this approach takes ~3s for 100k rows in df1.
# function to select random value; if the bin had no values, give np.nan
def get_rand(idx):
    try:
        return random.choice(filtered[idx])
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan

# Group continuous variables B, C
bins_B = np.arange(0,52.5,2.5)
bins_C = np.arange(0,105,5)

df1['b_group'] = pd.cut(df1['B'],bins_B)
df1['c_group'] = pd.cut(df1['C'],bins_C)

df2['b_group'] = pd.cut(df2['B'],bins_B)
df2['c_group'] = pd.cut(df2['C'],bins_C)

# Get all combinations of groups
uniques = df1.groupby(['A','b_group','c_group']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

filtered = []
# assemble pre-filtered datasets with each possible binned combination
for r in uniques.iterrows():
    filtered.append(df2.loc[(df2['b_group']==r[1]['b_group'])&(df2['c_group']==r[1]['c_group'])&(df2['A']==r[1]['A'])]['D'].values)

# make multiindex for lookup of binned values
uniques['list_index'] = uniques.index
uniques = uniques.set_index(['A','b_group','c_group'])

# get multindices for each row in df1
indices = zip(df1['A'].values,df1['b_group'].values,df1['c_group'].values)
df1['ref_idx'] = uniques.loc[indices,'list_index'].values

# get the desired value
df1['D'] = df1['ref_idx'].apply(get_rand)


apply should make it quicker:
def returnD(A, B, C, df2):
    return df2.loc[(df2['A']==A)& \
               (df2['B']>=B-5)& \
               (df2['B']<=B+5)& \
               (df2['C'] >= C-10) & \
               (df2['C'] <= C+10),:]['D'].sample().values[0]
df1['D'] = df1.apply(lambda x: returnD(x.A, x.B, x.C, df2), axis=1)


I have also corrected the C criteria. I think yours in your question was wrong

Thanks for catching that, yes indeed C was wrong. I tried with apply, and it's only very slightly quicker. E.g., a 20,000 row sample df1 has a runtime for me of 21s (using my original code) and now has 19s using apply.
